# Search data on datagridview using combobox value. TextChanged?

Tags: vb.net

```
          Try
        con.Open()
        dt2 = New DataTable
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "Select Lname,Fname,Mname,Gender,Grade,Saint,SY from g7 where saint='" & cinfosection.Text & " and Lname  like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'' 

        End With
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt2)
        dgclassinfo.DataSource = dt2

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    da.Dispose()
    con.Close()
```

I'm using the code above to search data in dgv wherein the result changes everytime the user inputs per character (textbox.Textchanged). The problem is I want the user to search using the data in combobox(dropdownlist). everytime the user select different value from the combobox another result is displayed in dgv INSTANTLY

Anyhelp is appreciated

Comment: You can add it to `ComboBox1.TextChange` or `ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` Event .. it will still work. Just change the code `Lname  like %TextBox1.Text%` to: `Lname  like %ComboBox1.Text%`

Comment: Thanks soo much, Cheers

Comment: That is not searching a DGV at all but running a new query.  A new query is not needed to filter a datasource.  Most importantly, that is the wrong way to compose SQL (for a long time now) because it is dangerous and error prone.  Look at how the syntax highlighting is wrong - there is an error in it even though the post is not about that.